# Exportar a PDF con php y mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estimados señores estamos en un proyecto de registro de mascotas y ahora el propietario noes está pidiendo que la inscripción de la mascota se genere un pdf ,  estamos utilizando FPDF, lo que queremos es lo siguiente, que al momento de dar click en el icono exportar nos debe de generar un pdf con los campos del formulario, les pedimos nos ayuden, gracias. 
Estamos dejando codigo html, javascript, php, ya hemos probado de todos modos y la verdad no lo logramos, somos nuevos en este tema.

Otro dato más, estamos utilizando Ajax, para poder procesar los id del html, pero igual no lo logramos hacer funcionar.

```js
// Funcion genera pdf
function generaPDFRegidMascota() {
 
  var datosForm = $("#formMascotas").serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fichaenpdf.php",
    data: datosForm,
    success: function(r) {
      if (r == 1) {
        alert("Se genero");
      } else {
        alert("error");
      }
    }
  });
}

//llama a la funcion pdf
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#espotarPDF").click(function() {
    generaPDFRegidMascota();
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="formMascotas" name="formMascotas">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-4 tamaimagen text-center">
                                  <img src="" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail img-detaMascota" id="fotoMascota">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col" hidden>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="IdRegisMascota">Id Mascota</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="IdRegisMascota" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Id Mascota">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="numRegisMascota">Número registro</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numRegisMascota" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Número Registro">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nomMascota">Nombre</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomMascota" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Nombre Mascota">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="fechaNaciMascota">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaNaciMascota" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>                             
                            </div>                            
                          </div>                          
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar <i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="espotarPDF">Exportar <i class="far fa-file-alt"></i></button>
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar <i class="fas fa-save"></i></button> -->
                          </div>
                 </form>
```

```html
<?php
include 'plantillapdf.php';    

$IdRegisMascota = $_POST['IdRegisMascota'];
$numRegisMascota = $_POST['numRegisMascota'];

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFillColor(232, 232, 232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
// $pdf->Cell(70, 6, 'ID', 1, 0, 'C', 1);


$pdf->Cell(70, 6, ['Hola'], 1, 0, 'C', 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: que no genera el PDF

Comment: Hola. Si dices estar usando FPDF en tu pregunta dice: **...estamos utilizando FPDF,...**, estás usando mal el constructor: debes escribir `$pdf = new FPDF();` te **falta una F** inicial. Aún así creo que adicionalmente falte hacer una referencia del tipo `use \algun_path\FPDF;` para que la instrucción new FPDF() no derribe el sistema generando un error grave.

Comment: $pdf = new PDF() lo importamos de otro archivo  que es class PDF extends FPDF y esta en include 'plantillapdf.php';

Comment: Te sugiero que revises el log de errores, que te dirá exactamente qué está pasando y dónde. Puede que estes sacando algo por pantalla antes de generar el PDF o que necesites limpiar el buffer. [Revisa las respuestas en esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18172440/5587982) donde hay varias sugerencias con las cuales podrías probar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien estas buscando es la forma que al hacer click en un botón mediante `Ajax` se genere un `PDF` y se descargue, si es así espero te sirva mi respuesta

***1er Paso***

Lo primero es cambiar la forma de generar el `PDF` en la línea:

```php
$pdf->Output();
```

sustituirla por la siguiente:

```php
$pdfContent= $pdf->Output('S');

$salida= array(
    'name' => "export.pdf",
    'file' => "data:application/pdf;base64," . base64_encode($pdfContent)
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($salida);
```

Con esto le indicamos al `PHP` que lo que vamos a retornar es un objecto `JSON`, que contiene un `PDF` codificado en `base64`

***2do Paso***

El segundo paso es como vamos a procesar la respuesta en el ajax, debes cambiar las siguientes líneas:

```js
success: function(r) {
    if (r == 1) {
        alert("Se genero");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
}
```

Sustituirlas por:

```js
success: function(data) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = data.file;
    a.download = data.name;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
}
```

Lo que hacemos en estas líneas es recibir el objeto `JSON` que nos retorna el `PDF` y crear un enlace `a` para poder descargar el `PDF` y una vez creado hacemos click para que se descargue el `PDF` y eliminamos el enlace.

Comment: Gracias, pero una pregunta mas, donde imprimo esta variable $numRegisMascota = $_POST['numRegisMascota']; en el archivo PHP

Comment: Quieres que se imprima en el `PDF`?

Comment: Si gracias, lo que se quiere es al dar click en exportar, se debe generar el pdf con los datos del modal.

Comment: Deberias poder hacerlo de la siguiente forma `$pdf->Cell(70, 6, $numRegisMascota, 1, 0, 'C', 1);`   Igual te invito a leer la documentación de [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: Gracia lo logre, el error estaba en, var datosForm = $("#formMascotas").serialize();