# crear pdf dompdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

Buenas tardes comunidad espero que me puedan ayudar ya que no puedo cargar mi estilo en mi modelo ya cargue mi estilo pero aun así no se si no llega a el o cual sea el programa la carpeta donde tengo mi  estilo quiero que al  generar la vista se vea de la siguiente manera

lo primero que se muestra es la siguiente pantalla
[image: vista principal]

al entrar a mi **view**
se muestra la siguiente pantalla

[image: al ingresar a view]

los código que utilizo son los siguientes

**modelo**
en esta parte es donde se envía los datosy la forma en que se imprimirá mi archivo pdf  no se si podria imprimir desde otra parte

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Purchaseorder_model extends CI_Model
{
    function fetch()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('CustomerID', 'DESC');
        return $this->db->get('ordendecompra');
    }
    function fetch_single_details($customer_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('CustomerID', $customer_id);
        $data = $this->db->get('ordendecompra');
        $output = '<table width="100%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">';
        
        foreach($data->result() as $row)
        {
            

            $output .= '
            <tr>
            

  <div class="col-sm-8" >

    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>dist/img/imagen.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image  elevation-3" height="220px" width="690px"style="opacity: .8">

  
  </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4"  style="background-color:#dddddd">
    <p class="text-center"> <strong>ORDEN DE COMPRA</strong>.</p>
    <p><b>Referencia : </b> '.$row->Referencia.' </p>
                    <p><b>nombre : </b> '.$row->NProyecto.' </p>
                    <p><b>nombre : </b> '.$row->Fecha.' </p>
                    <p><b>nombre : </b> '.$row->Hora.' </p>
                    <p><b>nombre : </b> '.$row->TC.' </p>
                    <p><b>nombre : </b> '.$row->Version.' </p>
                    <p><b>nombre : </b> '.$row->Moneda.' </p>

            
  </p>
 </div>
<br />
  </div>  <div class="col-sm-6" >

 <p class="text-center"> <strong>Ordenado A:</strong>.</p>
    <p > <strong>nombre </strong>
    <?php echo $Apelllido Paterno; ?><br>
    <strong>N° Apelllido Materni </strong><?php echo $NProyecto; ?><br>
    <strong>FECHA </strong><?php echo $Fecha; ?><br>
    <strong>HORA </strong><?php echo $Hora; ?><br>

  </p>

  
  </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6" ">
    <p class="text-center"> <strong>Facturado A:</strong>.</p>
    <p > <strong>nombre </strong>
    <?php echo $nombre; ?><br>
    <strong>N° nombre </strong><?php echo $NProyecto; ?><br>
    <strong>nombre </strong><?php echo $Fecha; ?><br>
    <strong>nombre </strong><?php echo $Hora; ?><br>
    <strong>T.C. </strong><?php echo $TC; ?><br>
    <strong>nombre </strong><?php echo $Version; ?><br>
    <strong>nombre </strong><?php echo $Moneda; ?>
  </p>
 </div>
  
  </div>

            

                        </td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="'.base_url().'htmltopdf" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a></td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $output .= '</table>';
        return $output;
    }
}

?>
```

**controlador**

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HtmltoPDF extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Purchaseorder_model');
        $this->load->library('pdf');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['customer_data'] = $this->Purchaseorder_model->fetch();
        $this->load->view('htmltopdf', $data);
    }
    public function details()
    {
        if($this->uri->segment(3))
        {
            $customer_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $data['customer_details'] = $this->Purchaseorder_model->fetch_single_details($customer_id);
            $this->load->view('htmltopdf', $data);
        }
    }

    public function pdfdetails()
    {
        if($this->uri->segment(3))
        {
            $customer_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $html_content = '<h3 align="center">Convert HTML to PDF in CodeIgniter using Dompdf</h3>';
            $html_content .= $this->Purchaseorder_model->fetch_single_details($customer_id);
            $this->pdf->loadHtml($html_content);
            $this->pdf->render();
            $this->pdf->stream("".$customer_id.".pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**vista**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert HTML to PDF in CodeIgniter using Dompdf</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container box">
        <br />
        <h3 align="center">Convert HTML to PDF in CodeIgniter using Dompdf</h3>
        <br />
        <?php
        if(isset($customer_data))
        {
        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer ID</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>View in PDF</th>
                </tr>
            <?php
            foreach($customer_data->result() as $row)
            {
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row->CustomerID.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->ONombre.'</td>
                    <td><a href="'.base_url().'htmltopdf/details/'.$row->CustomerID.'">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="'.base_url().'htmltopdf/pdfdetails/'.$row->CustomerID.'">View in PDF</a></td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }
            ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        if(isset($customer_details))
        {
            echo $customer_details;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

lo que no se es como hacer que mi pdf se vea como mi vista ya que al entrar en vista en psd manda todo como una lista hacia abajo y necesito que se vea como mi vista o si me pueden ayudar a decirme como puedo imprimir de esta manera o tiene algun código para la creación de pdf

[referencial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330002/exportar-a-pdf-con-php-y-mysql)

Comment: @DBE y por qué no pones una respuesta con eso en vez de un comentario? :P

Comment: @DBE es que lo imprime desde el modelo no desde la vista

Comment: @maria lo pudiste resolver?

Comment: si pude resolverlo gracias